# How can I fit rectangles to an coarse mask in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to fit rectangles to a coarse mask using python.
Here is the example.

[example of input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQX5A.png)

Then, here is the expected result.

[example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw2m0.png)

Note that the rectangles have no rotation.

Comment: What u have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.